# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jacob.com.ComThread

Tags: jacob

I am running an existing application which should ideally be working fine.
But when I run the code in my machine the following code throws an exception

```
ComThread.InitMTA();
```

Exception`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jacob.com.ComThread`

I have jacob.jar in my class path(WEB-INF\lib) and has also placed the corresponding dll in my Windows System32 folder. Please help.

Also my windows is 64 bit but I run the 32 bit version of java (for both project and eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem as well. This is the exception you'll see when the jacob dll is not found. It's really throwing an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` in a static initializer, but that ends up not affecting you until you try to load a class whose static initializer failed. The version of the dll (32 or 64 bit) required needs to match the JVM. You have a few options:

1. If you're using something like Eclipse, then put the dll on your classpath or add to your Eclipse Run Configuration another classpath entry with the location of your dll.
2. If you're using webstart, then you'll need to use the `nativelib` entry for a jar containing the dll.
3. Add the location of your dll to the jvm using `java.library.path`
4. You can hardcode the path to the dll using [`jacob.dll.path`](http://jacob-project.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jacob-project/jacob/src/com/jacob/com/LibraryLoader.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a jacob.jar version，1.11 version try

Comment: try dll files in tomcat / bin below

Comment: I tried putting the dll files in tomcat/bin but it didnt work

Comment: How about /META-INF/JacobVersion.properties file?

Comment: version=1.17
build.iteration=01
build.date=03-August-2013 06\:30\:22

Comment: @sunysen... I tried with version 1.11 but still no success :(

Comment: At last I got it to work. I made sure my eclipse and project runs on 32 bit version of java and I also placed the dll file in jdk\bin